# How to pass method to functional component in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass method ref to functional component but somehow it doesn't work

Here is the function:

```
import { FaTrashAlt } from 'react-icons/fa';

const ArticlesData = props => {
    return(
        props.products.map(product => {
            return (   
                <tr>
                    <td>{product.name}</td>
                    <td>{product.description}</td>
                    <td>{product.price}$</td>
                    <td>
                        <span className="removeProduct--Container" onClick={props.click}>
                            <FaTrashAlt className="remove--Icon" />
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            )
        }).reverse()
    )
}

export default ArticlesData;
```

Here is the request I'm trying to pass:

```
onRemove = (id) => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:5000/products/:${id}/delete`, {
        method: 'POST'
    })
}
```

And here is how I pass:

```
<ArticlesData products={this.state.products} click={this.onRemove}/>
```

Update:

controller:

```
router.post('/:id/delete', (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log(req.params.id)
        productService.deleteOne(req.params.id)
        res.status(200)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
})
```

service:

```
function deleteOne(id) {
    return Product.deleteOne({_id: id});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the function with parameter id.
I'm assuming your `product` object has `id` attribute:

```
import { FaTrashAlt } from 'react-icons/fa';

const ArticlesData = props => {
    return(
        props.products.map(product => {
            return (   
                <tr>
                    <td>{product.name}</td>
                    <td>{product.description}</td>
                    <td>{product.price}$</td>
                    <td>
                        <span className="removeProduct--Container" onClick={() => props.click(product.id)}>
                            <FaTrashAlt className="remove--Icon" />
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            )
        }).reverse()
    )
}

export default ArticlesData;
```

Comment: I tried it but nothing happend. Is it possible to be something in the passing in click={...} ?

Answer (score 0):

Change `ArticlesData` component's code

**from** `onClick={props.click}`

**to** `onClick={() => props.click(product.id)}`

---

Full code:

```
import React from "react";
import ArticlesData from "./ArticlesData";

export default class SomeName extends React.Component {
  onRemove = (id) => {
    console.log(id);
    fetch(`http://localhost:5000/products/:${id}/delete`, {
        method: 'POST'
    })
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <ArticlesData click={this.onRemove} />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

```
import { FaTrashAlt } from 'react-icons/fa';

const ArticlesData = props => {
    return(
        props.products.map(product => {
            return (   
                <tr>
                    <td>{product.name}</td>
                    <td>{product.description}</td>
                    <td>{product.price}$</td>
                    <td>
                        <span className="removeProduct--Container" onClick={() => props.click(product.id)}>
                            <FaTrashAlt className="remove--Icon" />
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            )
        }).reverse()
    )
}

export default ArticlesData;
```

[CodeSandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-pine-lbq1q?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I tried it but nothing happend. Is it possible to be something in the passing in click={...} ?

Comment: It should work. Live demo link: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-pine-lbq1q?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check working live `codesandbox` demo.

Comment: I'm using MERN Stack. I see that in router.post delete request when I log the id it is showing and in the browser console it says "Fetch finished loading: POST "http://localhost:5000/products/:606257f34a43ed20fc6546c4/delete". But it doesn't want to delete :D the product is still there :D